# What's with border-left-image, border-right-image, border-top-image and border-bottom-image?

Tags: css

So, I'm one of those guys that prides himself on always using the most recent browser versions (except Internet Explorer of course - I don't speak about *that* browser).

I've come across [this awesome CSS3 website](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) that details the `border-image` property introduced in CSS3, including its expanded properties such as `border-left-image`, `border-right-image`, `border-top-image`, `border-bottom-image` and so forth.

As detailed [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image), this property is at least partially supported in most major browsers. So, all's good and well, right? Not so fast...

I'm able to get `border-image` to work as expected, but its expanded properties are not rendering. For example, `border-right-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 round round;` ain't doing anythang in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari!

`border-image` is relatively documented on our Internets, but there is exceedingly limited (i.e. less than ten results) on any of the expanded properties.

Any insight here from our CSS3 gurus?

Comment: If you used IE10, you'd see it technically supports more than Chrome does right now, if you exclude vendor prefixes ;)

Comment: Thank's for asking the question, my brain was starting to hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expanded `border-*-image` properties no longer exist in [the current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images), and haven't for a very long time.<sup>1</sup> If any browsers still implement those properties, they are non-standard, and you should not expect them to gain cross-browser support.

For what it's worth, CSS3.info is extremely outdated and doesn't update nearly as much these days, so I don't use it for references anymore. The tables at http://caniuse.com always refer to the current specs as far as possible (with annotations for special cases), so you need to ensure that you're looking at the latest specifications when reviewing features, especially those that are in draft and have yet to be standardized.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The expansion of `border-image` to its individual sides was a very old idea in the [Border module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-image-uri) (which the above CSS3.info page links to!), which was merged with the Background module, all of which happened many years ago. The merger happened back in 2005, and that was when the expanded properties were dropped, leaving us with [`border-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) and several other properties that don't pertain to box sides. Those properties haven't reappeared since; not even in Backgrounds and Borders level 4.</sub>

Comment: Well, that's disappointing - but thank you for the clarification. Looks like I'm off to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

See browser quirks.
Also I dont see anywhere that says you can use the full properties on border-right-image do you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think I recall browsing to that page, but I must have skipped past a few paragraphs. Upvoted and appreciative!